# Stuck simplifying a fractional expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ \frac { \frac { 1 }{ 1+x+h } -\frac { 1 }{ 1+x }  }{ h }  $$
$$ \frac { 1(1+x) }{ 1+x+h(1+x) } -\frac { 1(1+x+h) }{ 1+x(1+x+h) } $$
$$ \frac { -h }{ (1+x+h)(1+x) } \quad *\quad \frac { 1 }{ h } $$

This is what I have so far. I have no idea what my next step is. I get to:

$$\frac { -h }{ (1+x+h)(1+x)(h) } $$

and don't know where to go from here..

Comment: You could divide the numerator and denominator by $h$ and expand the parentheses.

Comment: You're there. "*" is just multiplication, which is normally not indicated explicitly in regular algebra. Remove it and `cancel the $h$'s' (in reality, you're dividing numerator and denominator by $h$).

Comment: numerator has "-h"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac { \frac { 1 }{ 1+x+h } -\frac { 1 }{ 1+x }  }{ h }\cdot \frac{1/h}{1/h} = \frac{1}{h(1+x+h)} - \frac{1}{h(1+x)} = \frac{(1+x) - (1+x+h)}{h(1+x+h)(1+x)}=\frac{-h}{h(1+x+h)(1+x)}$$

The $h$ cancels, leaving us with $$\frac{-\require{cancel}\cancel h}{\cancel{h}(1+x+h)(1+x)} = \left(-\frac {1}{(1+x+h)(1+x)}\right)$$

Comment: The textbook answer saids it is:

$$-\frac { 1 }{ (1+x+h)(1+x) }$$

Comment: That is the answer. The h's cancel. I assumed, perhaps wrongly, that this was part of a limit problem. I'll edit to take that part out.

Comment: So the h's cancel and leave a -1? I am so confused right now.

I now see the mistake I made that didn't turn the h in the numerator negative.

Comment: We have $-h$ in the numerator, and a *factor* $h$ in the denominator. $$\frac{-h}{h(1+x+h)(1+x)} = \frac{h(-1)}{h(1+x+h)(1+x)} = \frac hh\cdot \frac{-1}{(1+x+h)(1+x)} = 1\cdot \frac{-1}{(1+x+h)(1+x)} = \frac{-1}{(1+x+h)(1+x)}$$